# How to reference multiple JS API's that use the same references for different data?

Tags: javascript, html, api

How can I reference multiple JS API's that use the same references but contain different data? I want to be able to reference the API for multiple Rust servers to get the player count of the individual server then display it on part of the page.

Here is an example of what I mean:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
 <head>
    <script src="https://api.rust-servers.info/embed.js?id=1"></script>
   <script src="https://api.rust-servers.info/embed.js?id=2"></script>
  </head>
  
  <a>Server 1</a>
  <a><script>document.write(players_cur);</script> / <script>document.write(players_max);</script> Players Online</a>
  
  <a>Server 2</a>
  <a><script>document.write(players_cur);</script> / <script>document.write(players_max);</script> Players Online</a>
  
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the scripts you reference just define a global variable, you can just interpose a script of your own to move the value elsewhere:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://api.rust-servers.info/embed.js?id=1"></script>
    <script> players_cur1 = players_cur; players_max1 = players_max; </script>
    <script src="https://api.rust-servers.info/embed.js?id=2"></script>
    <script> players_cur2 = players_cur; players_max2 = players_max; </script>
  </head>
  
  <a>Server 1</a>
  <a><script>document.write(players_cur1);</script> / <script>document.write(players_max1);</script> Players Online</a>
  
  <a>Server 2</a>
  <a><script>document.write(players_cur2);</script> / <script>document.write(players_max2);</script> Players Online</a>
  
</html>
```